# ¿Como buscar una palabra en todos los Stored Procedures de una base de datos SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Estoy trabajando con un sistema donde, para variar, lo antiguos programadores no dejaron documentación y necesito saber en que SPs se hacen inserts y/o updates a una tabla en particular.

Entonces lo que requiero es una instrucción que me regrese el nombre de los SPs donde se utiliza dicha tabla

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La forma más clásica y disponible en casi cualquier versión de SQLServer es buscar las dependencias de la tabla mediante [`sp_depends`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
EXEC sp_depends @objname = 'El_nombre_de_la_tabla'
```

Es importante notar que este `sp` en algún momento será deprecado, por lo que se recomienda el uso de las vistas `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` y `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`

Otra forma bastante práctica, es buscar por el contenido del código,  la tabla en la vista `syscomments`, esto debería retornar todos los `sp's` y `triggers` que tengan el texto que estás buscando.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(so.id)
       FROM syscomments sc
       INNER JOIN sysobjects so
             ON so.id = sc.id
       WHERE sc.text LIKE '%El_nombre_de_la_tabla$'
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que buscar en el texto de la columna `Routine_Definition` de la tabla  `Information_Schema.Routines`. 
Con la función `PatIndex` localizas si el texto buscado existe

```
Select Specific_Catalog as Database_Name, Routine_Name as Nombre, Routine_Definition
from Information_Schema.Routines 
Where PatIndex('%TextoBuscado%', Routine_Definition) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas de hacerlo. Puedes hacerlo directamente por medio de código con las vistas del sistema.

```
SELECT  o.name, 
        o.type_desc,
        m.definition
FROM sys.objects o
JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON p.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE m.definition LIKE '%PalabraClave%';
```

También puedes usar herramientas de terceros como [SQL Search de Redgate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) que permite buscar en múltiples bases de datos dentro de la misma instancia. Lo mejor, es que esta herramienta es gratuita. (Mi recomendación es simplemente por el uso y no por alguna relación comercial con la empresa)